# Inserting Data using MERN to Mongo only stores the ID

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have only just started off with MERN and currently struggling to understand why MongoDB will store anything except for generating the ID. Although, the status code for the API shows as 200 upon running the application, the Database stores something like this:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"613c98f76daf3b1d94cbbe6b"},
    "firstName":null,
    "lastName":null,
    "email":null
}
```

The code for both the frontend and backend are below:

The React Component from which the API call is being made

```
export default class TableScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        isVisible: false,
        position: "centre"
    }

    openDialog = () => {
        this.setState((state, props) => ({
            isVisible: true
        }))
    }

    closeDialog = () => {
        this.setState((state, props) => ({
            isVisible: false
        }))
    }

    onChangeFirstName = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            firstName : e.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeLastName = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            lastName : e.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeEmail = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            email : e.target.value
        })
    }

    addUser = () => {     //This is the api call
        const requestOption = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email)
        }
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/add", requestOption)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => this.openDialog()}>
                    Add
                </Button>
                {/* <UserList></UserList> */}
                <Dialog open={this.state.isVisible} onClose={() => this.closeDialog()} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>
                            To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
                            occasionally.
                        </DialogContentText>
                        <TextField
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            id="firstName"
                            label="First name"
                            type="email"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={this.onChangeFirstName}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            id="lastName"
                            label="Last name"
                            type="email"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={this.onChangeLastName}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            id="email"
                            label="Email"
                            type="email"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
                        />
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.closeDialog()} color="primary">
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        //The button that invokes the API
                        <Button onClick={() => this.addUser()} color="primary"> 
                            Add
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The Backend :

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    
    const app = express();
    
    const mongoDb = require('mongodb');
    
    const MongoClient = mongoDb.MongoClient;
    
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://coolhack069:XzC6N7dOyUeQl8M9@cluster0.kz6v9.mongodb.net/crud?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    
    app.use(cors());
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    const port = 3001;
    
    app.post('/api/add', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req);
    
        // const user = req.body;
        const fName = req.body.firstName;
        const lName = req.body.lastName;
        const email = req.body.email;
    
        client.connect(err => {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            
                const collection = client.db('crud').collection('data');
                // const storeData = user;
                const storeData = {"firstName" : fName, "lastName" : lName, "email" : email};
                collection.insertOne(storeData, function(err, result) {
                    res.send(result);
                    client.close();
                });
            })
        });
app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Application listening at http://localhost:${port}`) 
});
```

The `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing the JSON middleware.
Can you please share your server entry file?

Comment: I'm quite new to this. Are you asking for the code that is meant for establishing a connection with MongoDB? If not, can you please tell me where to find it?

Comment: What command you are using to run the server? Share your **package.json** file content. I need to see the **scripts** object specifically.

Comment: I use node index.js to run the server. I have now added the package.json in the question like you asked

Comment: This **index.js** is your entry file, your application starts from this file. So now, can you please share the content of this file? I need to see if you are using any middleware for parsing the body.

Comment: Backend updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237032/discussion-between-coolhack7-and-ammar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the API function in the `TableScreen` component. I modified the requestOption object in the addUser method by adding a `header` and changing the `body` a bit. The code snippet is as follows:

```
addUser = () => {     //This is the api call
        const requestOption = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({firstName: this.state.firstName, lastName : this.state.lastName, email: this.state.email})
        }
        fetch("http://localhost:3002/api/add", requestOption)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
    }
```

I just realized that I have defined the backend to handle data in JSON. `app.use(express.json());` is the line that does this. So accordingly, the backend would expect to receive any data that we would like to store in the same format. So the very first thing we are required to do is ensure that the data sent is in the very same format and we do that by defining the headers key which basically is meant for intimating the backend that the content it would be receiving will be in JSON.
The `body` key is then defined to send the data in an object format.
If you check this line in the initial code in the question, the `JSON.stringify` method looked like `body: JSON.stringify(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email)` which is wrong as we weren't sending the data in the format the backend expects. So the simple fix would be to add this line `this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email` within a pair of braces `{}` to convert this to an object as shown in the modified snippet above.
I would invite others to edit this answer if it doesn't sound right.

P.S : This is ideal for both the POST and PUT requests

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say like this. I can only give some tips one of which will probably solve it:
First, try using TypeScript, and DTOs (data transfer object), that would eliminate the possible typo issues between front and backend.
Then try checking the res.body values. That's also easier if you cast it to a typed DTO since you'd know which properties should it have. After you debug/log the req.body you'll see if it has the data or is it full of null values. If you get to this step, you can either fix the backend, or the frontend accordingly.
If you are communicating between client and server, for properties in the res.body it's really useful to have a function that gets the value while throwing an error if it's null or undefined. Like this:

```
const descriptorCode = withValueOrBadRequest(req.query.descriptorCode);
```

Also, try naming your variables in a more meaningful way: lName -> lastName
This also helps you to eliminate possible bugs, and typos, and will make you understand your code more yourself :)

*Also also it's not necessary to use quote marks ("") in JS objects, their properties can be defined without quotes. Like so:

```
{
   firstName: "Ben" 
}
```